# local sphinx generates autodoc members from docstrings, readthedocs does not

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs, autodoc

I have a [small project](https://github.com/alb-garcia/nix_shell_utils) at github. The package does not have external dependencies, and all the source is included in a single `__init__.py` file. In the `./docs` folder, I just have 2 `rst` files: an `index.rst` with some intro and a `nix_shell_utils.rst` file where the package members are automatically described from their docstrings:

nix_shell_utils.rst file

```
nix_shell_utils package                                                                                                                                                                                     
=========================                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                            
.. automodule:: nix_shell_utils                                                                                                                                                                             
   :members:                                                                                                                                                                                                
   :undoc-members:                                                                                                                                                                                          
   :show-inheritance:
```

The `./docs/conf.py` is quite standard:

```
# Configuration file for the Sphinx documentation builder.
#
# For the full list of built-in configuration values, see the documentation:
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))

# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#project-information

project = 'nix_shell_utils'
copyright = '2022, Alberto Garcia Izquierdo'
author = 'Alberto Garcia Izquierdo'
release = '0.0.1'

# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#general-configuration
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
    'sphinx.ext.autosummary',
    'sphinx.ext.napoleon'
]


templates_path = ['_templates']
exclude_patterns = ['_build', 'Thumbs.db', '.DS_Store']

# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#options-for-html-output

html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'
#html_static_path = ['_static']

# -- Options for autodoc ----------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#configuration

# Automatically extract typehints when specified and place them in
# descriptions of the relevant function/method.
autodoc_typehints = "description"

# Don't show class signature with the class' name.
autodoc_class_signature = "separated"

autodoc_member_order = 'bysource'
```

when generating documentation locally with `make html` the process goes OK: when clicking on the `nix_shell_utils` link in the `index.html` page, I get to the `nix_shell_utils.html` page, where all the members of the package are rendered correctly by `:automodule:` from their docstrings:

However, when I tried to do the same in [readthedocs.org](https://readthedocs.org), the build process terminates OK, but when clicking on the `nix_shell_utils` link at the documentation index, I just get a page with the title, "Module Contents" header, and nothing else. Readthedocs does not render the documentation of the package members from their docstrings.

My `.readthedocs.yaml` is pretty standard

```
version: 2                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                            
build:                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  os: "ubuntu-22.04"                                                                                                                                                                                        
  tools:                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    python: "3.10"                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                            
python:                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  install:                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    - method: pip                                                                                                                                                                                           
      path: .
```

And the log from the readthedocs building process does not indicate any problem:

```
Running Sphinx v5.3.0
making output directory... done
[autosummary] generating autosummary for: index.rst, nix_shell_utils.rst
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 2 source files that are out of date
updating environment: [new config] 2 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [ 50%] index
reading sources... [100%] nix_shell_utils

looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [ 50%] index
writing output... [100%] nix_shell_utils

generating indices... genindex py-modindex done
highlighting module code... [100%] nix_shell_utils

writing additional pages... search done
copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index in English (code: en)... done
dumping object inventory... done
Updating searchtools for Read the Docs search... build succeeded.

The HTML pages are in _build/html.
```

I have looked at similar questions in stackoverflow, but for most of them either the package to be documented has not been installed prior to run the doc build (not my case), or they have external dependencies that have not been installed (I don't have any). I've tried to set up exactly the same environment locally and in readthedocs (`ubuntu 22.04`, `Python 3.10`, `Sphinx v5.30`) and also run the same command as in readthedocs locally

```
python -m sphinx -T -E -b html -d _build/doctrees -D language=en . _build/html
```

But again, locally autodoc members are rendered correctly, while on readthedocs they don't.

Any idea of why this is happening?

Comment: https://nix-shell-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nix_shell_utils.html looks OK to me.

Comment: @mzjn - yes, as the asnwer below suggested, it was just a browser cache issue :-S Thanks for checking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, when I tried to do the same in readthedocs.org, the build
> process terminates OK, but when clicking on the nix_shell_utils link
> at the documentation index, I just get a page with the title, "Module
> Contents" header, and nothing else. Readthedocs does not render the
> documentation of the package members from their docstrings.

Maybe it was a cache issue? I do see the documentation properly at https://nix-shell-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nix_shell_utils.html

It shows the docs for `nix_shell_utils.mkdir`, `nix_shell_utils.cp` and many other functions.

Comment: Ouch! I was scratching my head for over 30 builds as to why this was happening - just cleaning my browser cache did the trick (I'm new to readthedocs) ... Thanks a lot Manuel! :-)